# Stanford dataset to CoreML

Tags: coreml, coremltools

I have a dataset, downloaded from [link](http://ai.stanford.edu/~jkrause/cars/car_dataset.html).
I know about `coremltool` (created by **Apple**).

*The question is:* 
is it possible to **convert** Stanford `dataset` to `CoreML` ?
If yes - can somebody give me **instructions** ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is asked so often, that finally I've decided to draw a diagram.

[image: Can I have gasoline to tractor convertor plz?]

Explanation:

- Dataset is a "fuel" that you put into your model to make it work.
- Model is a machine learning algorithm: neural network, decision tree etc.
- Supported ML frameworks and models are listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/converting_trained_models_to_core_ml) together with the instructions for conversion.

Comment: Wow, you are great :)
Thanks and sorry for stupid question ! But it helps me

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own .mlmodel file using your own data set with a python script and a python library called coremltools. You can train your model using sklearn, keras, etc. and can customize what is uses to train like SVM, kNN, regression, and so on. Then you save it as a .mlmodelfile and drop that into your project. This video is helpful:
 https://youtu.be/T4t73CXB7CU